# Verify YouTube Premium member via YouTube Data API

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

How can I verify whether a user has "YouTube Premium" account via YouTube Data API. I've gone through all the APIs listed in the reference, but couldn't find any.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/

Answer (score 0):

The Youtube api is channel based.  This means that all the information is about a specific channel there is no information about the user themselves. That information is not currently available in the YouTube api.  You should consider submitting a featuer request to google requesting that they add this information to the api.

You can find the YouTube issue forum here. [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803)